# JavaScript - Are values read from text box escaped?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a text field in html and the input is required to be of format domain\user. The regular expression I am using to enforce this is `var x = /\S+\\\S+/;` Let us say the input value in text box is x\y. When I get the value of text box through `$('#textbox-name').val()` and then perform a reg-ex match the return value is false. But when I do `$('#textbox-name').val().replace('\\', '\\\\');`and perform a match, the result is true. Doesn't the val() function escape the return values?

Comment: Why do you have 3 `\\\\` in your regex?

Comment: @Amit: the first two indicate a literal backslash. The last one is part of "\S" for non-whitespace.

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the slash before the regex match. I tried exactly what you tried and it works fine. Post your exact code - maybe it's something else.

Comment: ^You are right. I wrote a sample program - https://jsfiddle.net/a9oexssa/. I don't have to escape. But doesn't work in my production code. Not really sure what is wrong. This is exactly what I try to do.

Comment: @BrianStephens yeah, you're right, I got confused by the abundance of them ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. It returns the entered text